# How to get the complete Binary Data of a byte array on another String in Java

Tags: java

I Have used a byte Array like this:

```
byte[] fileContents =  Files.readAllBytes(path);
    for(int i = 0 ,j = 1; i <fileContents.length ; i++)
        FileContents += Integer.toBinaryString(fileContents[i]);

        System.out.println(FileContents);
```

but when I run this on a File containing :

```
Ananay
```

it shows this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.String.replace(String.java:2239)
at UEX.<init>(UEX.java:21)
at test.testEncryption(test.java:38)
at __SHELL54.run(__SHELL54.java:5)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:743)
```

Thanks in advance.

(I prefer to use a String in this case even though it is not recommended)

Comment: Is your `FileContents` variable initialized? because if it is not then it won't work

Comment: No. Read the stack trace. The exception is thrown from the String.replace() method, which is itself called from the constructor in UEX, at line 21. So it has nothing to do with the code you posted, which never calls replace().

Comment: @Lino Thanks a lot! That was Exactly what it is.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks to you too. I had removed the replace function but put its Stack Trace up